# For $S \subseteq P$ that is closed under meet, there exists smallest $s \in S$ so that $p \leq s$ $\forall p \in P$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let P be a poset and let $S \subseteq P$ be so that $\forall p \in P$ there exists smallest $s \in S$ so that $p \leq s$.
Then the subset S is called a *closure system* of P.

If P is a complete lattice then the closure systems of P are those subsets that are closed under infima (=meet). So if $x, y \in S$ then $x \wedge y \in S$.

How to prove that for a subset that is closed under infima, there exists smallest $s \in S$ so that $p \leq s$ $\forall p \in P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will rephrase the problem a bit. Assume a lattice (in the sense of order theory) $(A, R)$ together with a subset $K \subseteq A$ such that $\mathrm{inf}\ X \in K$ for any subset $X \subseteq K$. We claim that in such a situation $K$ is a closure system on the ordered set $(A, R)$.

To show this consider an arbitrary $x \in A$ and write $M=[x, \to)_R \cap K$ for simplicity. By hypothesis, since $M \subseteq K$ we infer that $\mathrm{inf}\ M \in K$. Furthermore, it is clear by construction that $x$ is a lower bound for $M$, whence $x \leqslant_R \mathrm{inf}\ M$. These two observations combined entail the relation $\mathrm{inf}\ M \in M$, which signifies that $\mathrm{inf}\ M$ is the *minimum* of $M$. Since this is the case for any $x \in A$, $K$ is indeed a closure system.